# Unsupported class file major version 65 - Java 21

Tags: java, spring

I've upgraded my project from Java 11 -> Java 21 and been facing a couple of problems since so. I'm trying to run ArchitectureTests using ArchUnit library but keep getting the same error as below:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 65
    at com.tngtech.archunit.thirdparty.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:199)
    at com.tngtech.archunit.thirdparty.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:180)
    at com.tngtech.archunit.thirdparty.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
    at com.tngtech.archunit.thirdparty.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:287)
    at com.tngtech.archunit.core.importer.ClassFileProcessor.process(ClassFileProcessor.java:65)
    at com.tngtech.archunit.core.importer.ClassFileImporter.importLocations(ClassFileImporter.java:336)
    at com.tngtech.archunit.core.importer.ClassFileImporter.importPackages(ClassFileImporter.java:209)
    at com.tngtech.archunit.core.importer.ClassFileImporter.importPackages(ClassFileImporter.java:220)
    at tech.seedz.contract.architecture.ArchitectureTest.setup(ArchitectureTest.java:22)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:728)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptLifecycleMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:128)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptBeforeEachMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:78)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeMethodInExtensionContext(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:520)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$synthesizeBeforeEachMethodAdapter$23(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:505)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachMethods$3(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:174)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachMethods(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:134)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
```

I've declared gradle 8.6 in my gradle-wrapper file and am using Java 21. Any possible solution for the above issue?

I tried changing gradle JVM to 17 but that didn't help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Comment: @Shivakumar Don't believe this is a duplicate of that Q&A. It's not Java that doesn't support the class file version, but rather ArchUnit (or more specifically, the version of ASM being used by ArchUnit).

Comment: @Hadi Which version of ArchUnit are you using? Have you tried updating to the latest version if you aren't already using it?

Comment: testImplementation 'com.tngtech.archunit:archunit-junit5:0.23.1'

Comment: You're using a library which has a shaded version of ASM, and that version of ASM doesn't support the class versions from Java 21.

Answer (score 1):

testImplementation 'com.tngtech.archunit:archunit:1.2.1'

importing the above solved the issue